# Receiving error when assigning double to double 2D array C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, double

Im having a problem assigning a double to a 2D double array. I keep getting the error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double *’ from type ‘double’
   triangle[j][i] = weight;
```

Main Declarations:

```
  int bottom_row = 0, row = 0, col = 0;
  col = row = bottom_row = getRowSize(bottom_row);
  col--, row--;
  double triangle[row][col]; //Initialize array at size of bottom row
```

Recursive Function:

```
void triangleWeight2(int row, int col, double *triangle[row][col], int i, int j){ //Part 2 of triangleWeight
      if(i - 1 == j){
        return;
      }
      double weight = 0;
      printf("Triangle[%d][%d] = ", j, i);
      scanf("%f", &weight);
      if(weight <= 0){ //Checking if weight is positive
        printf("Invalid input. Enter another weight\n");
        triangleWeight2(row, col, triangle, i, j);
        return;
      }
      triangle[j][i] = weight;
      triangleWeight2(row, col, triangle, i + 1, j);
      return;
    }
```

Problem seems to be here

```
triangle[j][i] = weight;
```

And im not sure what to do to fix this. Changing `double weight = 0;` to `int weight = 0` seems to fix the error but i cant error decimal numbers that way. How would i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double *triangle[row][col]` declares a parameter of type array of array of pointers to double.

Therefore `triangle[j][i]` has type `double*`.

You want to pass `triangle` as `double triangle[row][col]`.

Unrelated to the particular error, but the format specifier for a double in `scanf` is `%lf`, not `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*` from `double *triangle[row][col]` in the function prototype. An array name is, by definition, a pointer to its first element.